# Ошибка при открытии таблицы через админ панель сайта Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-admin

В проект Django импортировал БД SQLite содержащую записи. При открытии таблиц, содержащих поля с типом Date, через админ панель возникает ошибка (см ниже), с открытием других таблиц данной БД ошибок не возникает.

Ошибка

```
return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'19 00:00:00'
```

Файл models.py

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    registry_number = models.TextField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    link_to_contract = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_conclusion_of_a_contract = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Contract'
```

[image: Пример записей в БД]

Comment: Судя по ошибке, там код пытается значение просто по дефисам разбить, каждую часть привести к целому числу - т.е. предполагается, что в таблице дата в виде строки "2014-01-01", а у вас там еще время. Попробуйте тип указать DateTimeField вместо DateField.

Answer (score 0):

**Проблема в том, что в таблице БД для столбца указан тип данных Data, а не DateTime.** Пробовал указать в models.py для date_conclusion_of_a_contract **DateTimeField** без результата. Скачал SQLite Studio и с помощью него изменил столбцы в таблице БД на тип данных DateTime. По новой провел миграцию. Таблицы через панель администратора стали открываться